# How to use select query in dropdown? in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have to much data in my table which I bind in my dropdown, but now I want just those data which i want. Can i implement select query here?

This is my controller and i bind table like this...

```
var accounts = db.gl_m_acc.ToList();
            foreach (var item in accounts)
            {
                GetAccountsCH ac = new GetAccountsCH();
                ac.acc_no = item.acc_no;
                ac.acc_des = item.acc_des;
                Gl_t_Vcr_model.acc.Add(ac);
            }
```

This is my View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.acc_no, new SelectList(Model.acc, "acc_no", "acc_des"), "<---Select--->", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%;" })
```

Comment: **I want just those data which i want.** So which data would you want? Could you please show those data?

Comment: why      GetAccountsCH ac = new GetAccountsCH(); inside the loop?

Comment: You can just use `foreach(var item in accounts.Where(a => a.yourfield == value))`

Comment: I want some of my data according to my select query, like i want "acc_no" where acc_des="XYZ".


This is "GetAccountsCH" is in my model class, here i bind data of account
in my model it is like:  
public List<GetAccountsCH> acc = new List<GetAccountsCH>();